# White space above back ground image

Tags: html, css

What is the white space above this background image caused by? I can kinda fix it using float by the content inside is still held down. Also it doesn't show in this example but if you can tell my how I would make the background image stretch to fit the content vertically it would be appreciated. Thanks

```
<div class="welcome-section">
        <div class="welcome-content-wrap">
            <img src="images/welcomeTransparent.png">

            <p><span class="text-style">WELCOME</span> to Popsie's of Bramhope a modern, local<br> Yorkshire fish and chip shop. At Popsie's all our food is hand<br> prepared by Popsie's Dad in the shop's kitchen every day.</p>
            <p>All our fish is sourced from sustainable sources.</p>
            <p>We cook fish to order so that it isn't left to dry out under lights,<br> like in too many chip shops.</p>
            <p>Our potatoes are from local Yorkshire & Lincolnshire farms and<br> we pride ourselves on using the best and freshest ingredients.</p>

            <img id="image-m" src="images/shutterstock_164403170.jpg">
             <img id="image-l" src="images/National-federation-of-fish-logo.png">
            <img id="image-r" src="images/CSSMSClogo.png">
        </div>
    </div>

.welcome-section{
    background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/5412/water-blue-ocean.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    /*float: left;*/
}

.welcome-content-wrap{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    text-align: center;
}

.welcome-content-wrap img{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.welcome-content-wrap p{
    color: #fff;
    margin: 25px;
}

.text-style{
    font-family: outstanding;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kfj5ucL0/

Comment: The great thing about jsfiddle is that you can keep tinkering with it. Try removing all padding and margins one by one until you find the one that is the source of the extra space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white space is caused by the margin you've set.

```
.welcome-content-wrap img{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 50px auto; /* <-- here */
}
```

Try

```
.welcome-content-wrap img{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

To stretch to cover vertically try adding `min-height: 100vh;` to the class.

Answer (score 1):

> Also it doesn't show in this example but if you can tell my how I would make the background image stretch to fit the content vertically it would be appreciated.

Use `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="welcome-section">
        <div class="welcome-content-wrap">
            <img src="img/anywhere.png">

            <p><span class="text-style">WELCOME</span> to Popsie's of Bramhope a modern, local<br> Yorkshire fish and chip shop. At Popsie's all our food is hand<br> prepared by Popsie's Dad in the shop's kitchen every day.</p>
            <p>All our fish is sourced from sustainable sources.</p>
            <p>We cook fish to order so that it isn't left to dry out under lights,<br> like in too many chip shops.</p>
            <p>Our potatoes are from local Yorkshire & Lincolnshire farms and<br> we pride ourselves on using the best and freshest ingredients.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="welcome-content-wrap">
            <img id="image-m" src="images/shutterstock_164403170.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="welcome-content-wrap">
             <img id="image-l" src="images/National-federation-of-fish-logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="welcome-content-wrap">
            <img id="image-r" src="images/CSSMSClogo.png">
        </div>
    </div>
<style>
.welcome-section{
    background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/5412/water-blue-ocean.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 555px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.welcome-content-wrap{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    text-align: center;
}

.welcome-content-wrap img{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.welcome-content-wrap p{
    color: #fff;
}

.text-style{
    font-family: outstanding;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
</style>
```